# Como identificar o applicationId?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Estou implementando o *FireBase* no meu projeto, mas ao realizar o cadastro do meu aplicativo no console do *FireBase* ele solicita o nome do pacote (*applicationId*).

No *help* da página aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Em geral, o nome do seu pacote é o applicationId no arquivo "*build.gradle*" no nível do seu app

Porém não encontrei o arquivo *build.gradle* no meu projeto.

Alguém pode me informar onde encontro o *applicationId* no Xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que ele está solicitando é o nome do `Package` do seu aplicativo.

Para encontrá-lo, clique com o botão direito no seu projeto e selecione `Properties`.

Na tela aberta, selecione *Android Manifest* e procure pelo item *Package name*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Normalmente** o `package` do seu aplicativo é o nome dele ponto (.) ele mesmo. Se o seu aplicativo se chama *MyApp*, o package dele vai ser *MyApp.MyApp*.